# How to resolve: media scanning not yet finished

Tags: android

I am currently developing 2D action game on Android platform. It works well on emulator, but when I test this game on device (specially Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830), sometimes it hangs with vibration. While examining the device logs, I found basically following 3 type of error messages very frequent:

02-25 06:33:05.510: ERROR/Tethering(167): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring

02-25 06:29:30.120: ERROR/libgps(296): dns_query_loop: gethostbyname failed. h_errno 2

02-25 06:20:40.687: ERROR/MTP-LAUNCHER(922): media scanning not yet finished.

Out of above error messages, the last one comes usually when game got hang on device. There is no need for internet connection & no apis accessing internet is used in the code. I doubt that this ERROR/MTP-LAUNCHER(922): media scanning not yet finished. error is causing my game to hang with vibration.

I am eagerly looking for suggestions for this problem.